# My python discord bot wont function at all

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm coding my first bot, and i keep on running into the same issue that the line of code: bot=discord.client() wont function. How do i fix this? Heres my code:

```
import discord
import os

from dotenv import load_dotenv #load .env funcs
load_dotenv() #stilll loading
DISCORD_TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN") #grab token

bot=discord.client() #grab client token

@bot.event #when bot is online
async def on_ready():
    guild_count = 0 #server counter
    for guild in bot.guilds: #go through guilds
        print(f"- {guild.id} (name: {guild.name})") #print server names
        guild_count = guild_count + 1 #add to server counter
    print("SampleDiscordBot is in " + str(guild_count) + " guilds.") #print server count
    
@bot.event #when new message is sent
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "test": #get message
        await message.channel.send("test") #send message

bot.run(DISCORD_TOKEN) #execute everything
```

the .env file's code is DISCORD_TOKEN = '(my bot's token)' I tried following other tutorials, all of them have the same error: that line of code wont work.

Comment: `discord.Client()` not `discord.client()` - [discord.py API reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#client)

Comment: How do you know that you have a problem on that line? Do you get an error message? Don't you think it would be a good idea to share this exact message with us so we might be able to help?

Comment: File "(my python directory)", line 8, in <module>
    bot=discord.client() #grab client token
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost correct.

You have a missing capitalization of the word Client on line 8. Instead of `bot=discord.client()` You should use `bot=discord.Client()` with a capital C.

Also, you're lacking the declaration of intents, which are a must in order to run your Bot and should be placed as an argument for when you call like this `discord.Client(intents=...)`.

Intents are a feature of Discord that tells the gateway exactly which events to send your bot, you can find more information [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=intents#discord.Intents).

Here is the working code with the corrections from above:

```py
import discord
import os

from dotenv import load_dotenv  # load .env funcs

load_dotenv()  # stilll loading
DISCORD_TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")  # grab token
intents = discord.Intents.all()

bot = discord.Client(intents=intents)  # grab client token


@bot.event  # when bot is online
async def on_ready():
    guild_count = 0  # server counter
    for guild in bot.guilds:  # go through guilds
        print(f"- {guild.id} (name: {guild.name})")  # print server names
        guild_count = guild_count + 1  # add to server counter
    print("SampleDiscordBot is in " + str(guild_count) + " guilds.")  # print server count


@bot.event  # when new message is sent
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "test":  # get message
        await message.channel.send("test")  # send message


bot.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)  # execute everything
```

Answer (score -1):

`bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix="!",intents=discord.Intents.all())`
If you got the env correctly thats the only mistake in your code.

Comment: This is incorrect. The error is with capitalization of the word Client (which is written as client without a capital C) and the lack of declaration of intents.

Comment: You also need intents and prefix, I just wrote commands.Bot because I work with that...

Comment: You're still partially correct. Prefix is not mandatory to load the Bot, in fact, you can even use prefix-less commands, you can read more [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=prefix#discord.ext.commands.Bot.command_prefix)

Answer (score -1):

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands 
from dotenv import load_dotenv #load .env funcs

load_dotenv() #stilll loading
DISCORD_TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN") #grab token

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="YOUR_PREFIX", intents=discord.Intents.default()) #grab client token

@bot.event #when bot is online
async def on_ready():
    guild_count = 0 #server counter
    for guild in bot.guilds: #go through guilds
        print(f"- {guild.id} (name: {guild.name})") #print server names
      guild_count += 1
    print("Bot is in " + str(guild_count) + " guilds.") #print server count
    
@bot.event #when new message is sent
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "test": #get message
        await message.channel.send("test") #send message

bot.run(DISCORD_TOKEN) #execute everything
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).